# how to calculate the sum of successive integers starting at 1 and ending at n by using a recursion function

Tags: c, recursion

My function gets a number and returns the sum of the numbers before the input including the input; however, i was wondering if it is possible to calculate the sum of successive integers starting at 1 and ending at n(as input)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int sum(int x){
    if(x>0)return x+sum(x-1);
    else return 0;
}
main(){
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);;
    printf("%d\n\n",sum(x));
}
```

I found the answer for my question, but the stackoverflow.com don't let me answer it. So, I'll answer it here:

It is really simple, all it needs is another argument for incrementation and the other one to keep track of the value inputed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int sum(int x,int t){
    if(t<=x) return t+sum(x,t+1);
    else return 0;
}
main(){
    int x;
    printf("enter int: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d\n",sum(x,0));
}
```

Comment: In what way does your code not already do what you want it to do?

Comment: There's a closed mathematical formula for it (`(x*(x+1))/2`). Recursion isn't necessary, but you've written looks like it will work.

Comment: Indeed, it works, but i wonder if I can do it starting from one to the input without using the mathematical formula.

Comment: Do you mean, how to add them up as 1 + 2 + 3 instead of 3 + 2 + 1?

Comment: Yes, and I've just found the answer and I posted with my question in the top because the website don't give me access to answer my question in the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

The sum of all the intergers smaller than `n`, and larger than `0` can be found with

```
 int sum = (n*(n+1))/2
```

which has much less overhead than a recursive function. But if you really want to then you function looks correct, I'd add some curly braces though:

```
int sum(int x){
  if(x>0) {
    return x+sum(x-1);
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The problem with the above function, is that is uses the stack for for memorisation, so you probably won't be able to calculate large `n`s. You can make your function tail recursive:

```
int sum(int x, int sum){
  if(x>0) {
    return sum(x-1, sum + x);
  }
  else {
     return sum;
  }
}
```

This wont use the stack to memorise your intermediate sums. However a simple loop is probably better, and if you want it to look really cryptic and effective, you can do:

```
int sum = (n*(++n))>>1
```

Comment: Your last line has undefined behaviour; it is not remotely clear which value will be calculated, and the compiler can produce any value at all and you can't complain.